# Android getSystemService TypeCastException

Tags: android, kotlin, service

I have the following code inside the onCreate method of my Application class

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE).also {
       MidiController.instance.midiManager = it as MidiManager
    }
}
```

When I test this code on my devices I don't have any issue with it but some users devices report the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4973)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1560)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5765)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException:
```

I suspect that the issue might be because I'm calling the getSystemService from the Application class instead of the Activity, is this a bad practice ? If not what could be the issue ? Thanks

Comment: Where, inside your Application, are you running this code? I have no issues running it inside `onCreate`

Comment: "is this a bad practice ?" -- that is perfectly normal. Is there more to the stack trace, beyond what you have posted?

Comment: Chances are that not all devices have midi feature and MidiManager system service returns null. Attempting to cast a null to kotlin nonnull type could explain the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes I guess not all devices with SDK over 23 have the midi feature. My mistake was checking the SDK version instead of using hasSystemFeature

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution should be using hasSystemFeature instead of checking the SDK version.

```
if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MIDI)) {
    getSystemService(Context.MIDI_SERVICE).also {
       MidiController.instance.midiManager = it as MidiManager
    }
}
```